# What other than fontsize does \normalsize change?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

My lualatex + memoir book is using a lot of rubber spacing.  I just realized that issuing a `\normalspace` changes a subsequent page break (and thus the entire document).  This is a little too fragile for me.  I want to understand what really causes the change so that I can control it a little better or at least understand what can bring this on.

the obvious change of `\normalsize` is that it changes the `\fontsize` (and perhaps `\baseskip`), but I have checked both and they are unchanged before and after.  so it must be doing quite a bit more.

the `\meaning\normalsize` tells me it is based on commands that are deeper down than I understand:

```
\long macro:->\@setfontsize \normalsize \@xpt \@xiipt \abovedisplayskip
10\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 5\p@ \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus 3\p@
\belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus 3\p@ \@minus 3\p@ \belowdisplayskip
\abovedisplayskip \let \@listi \@listI
```

could someone please explain exactly what it does?

regards, /iaw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\long macro:->
\@setfontsize \normalsize \@xpt \@xiipt
\abovedisplayskip10\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 5\p@
\abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus 3\p@
\belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus 3\p@ \@minus 3\p@
\belowdisplayskip\abovedisplayskip
\let \@listi \@listI
```

means that it is

```
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont % 10pt font on 12pt baseline
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{10pt plus 2pt mius 5pt}% space above math
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt plus 3pt}% short space above math
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip {6pt plus 3pt minus 3pt}% space below math
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{\abovedisplayskip}% same
\let \@listi \@listI % reset spaces in lists to normalsize defaults
```

Comment: +1. :-) It may be worth adding that only `\normalsize`, `\small`, and `\footnotesize` modify the math- and list-related spacing parameters. This is, presumably, because it's conceivable that lists and display-math material could occur if `\small` or `\footnotesize` are in force. In contrast, `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\large, `\Large`, etc change only the font size and the baselineskip, but no other parameters.

Comment: @Mico well it depends on the class of course. I don't know `memoir` that well so I didn't check, I just explained the code shown in the question

Comment: what is the recommended latex-y way to retain my own settings of displayskips when switching font sizes (on memoir with lualatex)?  etoolbox with `\apptocmd`?  `\patchcmd`?  renewcommand all the fonts?  some other mechanism?

Comment: @ivoWelch (re)define `\normalsize` I would simply copy the command from the class and use \rewcommand no point in patching it

Comment: @ivoWelch After your `\normalsize` just set the lengths you want. I guess that you have defined the lengths that you want before calling `\normalsize`, which sets the regular skips so respecify them afterwards.